# poshytip dynamic div id to content

Tags: jquery, tooltip

i have an anchor tag :

```
<a id='themeBtn$key' href='Javascript:void(0)' onclick=showThemeKeyowrds(this,$key)>".ucwords($value['THEME_NAME'])."</a>
```

where $key is an themeId.

Below is the JS function :

```
function showThemeKeyowrds(ele,themeId)
{
$("div [id^='themeBtn']").poshytip('hide');

if (!$(ele).data('poshytip')) 
      $(ele).poshytip({
        liveEvents: true,
        content: "theme"+themeId,
        showOn: 'none',
        alignTo: 'target',
        alignX: 'inner-left',
        offsetX: -20,
        offsetY: 10
});

$('#themeBtn'+themeId).poshytip('show');
 }
```

where div themeXXXXX is generated in foreach loop with "theme".$themeId.

While passing the div id as content to pshytip, it shows "themeXXXX" as content, but not the themeXXXX div's content ...

What could be the error?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are setting the text `theme"+themeId` as the content instead of the element to the tooltip plugin. So change `content: "theme"+themeId,` to `content: $("#theme"+themeId),`

```
if (!$(ele).data('poshytip')) 
      $(ele).poshytip({
        liveEvents: true,
        content: $("#theme"+themeId),
        showOn: 'none',
        alignTo: 'target',
        alignX: 'inner-left',
        offsetX: -20,
        offsetY: 10
});
```